# "Call to a member function mysql_query() on a non-object" when performing a query inside a function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function

```
<?php
function drop() {
    $query = "SELECT revenueCodeID, code FROM revenuecodetable";
    $result = $dbx->mysql_query($query);
    echo '<select>';
    echo '<option value="">Revenue Code</option>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['revenueCodeID'].'">'.$row['code'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
?>
```

And I have a page that calls the function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    require 'headerInfo.php';
    require 'revenueCodeDropdown.php';
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php drop(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

headerInfo.php allows for calling the database using $dbx.

When I try and call the function, I get

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function mysql_query() on a non-object in /var/www/legacy_nas/nas/revenueCodeDropdown.php on line 4
```

If I take the function syntax out it works fine. Any ideas to help fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `$dbx` as global

```
 function drop() {
     global $dbx;
     .....//rest of stuff
   }
```

OR

Pass object as function parameter

```
function drop($dbx) {
```

and call statement

```
<?php drop($dbx); ?>
```

You should understand the variable scope. Outer Variables are not available inside the function by default. They can be declared as global or can be passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Did you instantiate the `$dbx` object ?